# MySQL combine multiple rows based on condition and concatenate result in one field

Tags: mysql

I have some difficulties to build the query in MySQL to combine multiple rows result based on condition and concatenate result in one field.
I have following table structure:

table1: customers

```
customerID     feature_1       feature_2    feature_3
==========    =============    =========    =========
1             administrator    active       1000
2             moderator        blocked      9999
```

table2: orderdetails

```
OrderID       customerID    OrderDate       OrderdetailsName      OrderdetailsData
==========    ==========    ==========      ================      ================
1              1             1/1/2018       firstname             John
1              1             1/1/2018       lastname              Dow
1              1             1/1/2018       phone                 111111
2              2             2/1/2018       firstname             George
2              2             2/1/2018       lastname              Smith
2              2             2/1/2018       phone                 222222
```

Data in Both tables is linked by 'customerID' field

I would like to have a query giving following result as below:

```
OrderID   OrderDate    customerID    feature_3    FullName
=======   =========    ============  =========    ============
1         1/1/2018     1             1000         John Dow
2         2/1/2018     2             9999         George Smith
```

My problem is how to make the query to get as result full name in single field as its data/details is stored multiple rows based on given meta tag name (column 'OrderdetailsName' - firstname or lastname)
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried group_concat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using group concat with condition should work

```
SELECT customers.feature_3, orderdetails.OrderID, orderdetails.OrderDate, 
orderdetails.customerID, GROUP_CONCAT(if(orderdetails.OrderdetailsName = 'firstname' || 
orderdetails.OrderdetailsName = 'lastname', orderdetails.OrderdetailsData, '') SEPARATOR ' ') 
as fullname FROM customers join orderdetails on customers.customerID = 
orderdetails.customerID GROUP by customerID
```